# SwipeListView in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i wanted to implement swipelistview in monodroid.

so on each listview item i wanted to show two buttons with click event on them.

i been refering below link which is in java but i wanted to have this working in my c# / monodroid project

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

i have also refered the below link

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/

Please help me with some example for monodroid project.

Thanks
aaman

Comment: One of the nice things about Xamarin is that you can use existing Java components in your project. Download and build the project. You'll need to create a JAR file. Once you do that, you can create a new Java Bindings library. Reference the JAR file and it'll create a .NET assembly that you can reference in your Android project. Then you can use the component just like it was a native Android control.

Comment: @Kiliman Thanks a lot for your comment...can you please guide an example for the same, so that i can reference and create .Net assembly for the same

Comment: I have successfully implemented the swipelistview in monodroid, if any one want the source do let me know. Reference for Csharp SwipeListView https://github.com/chrisriesgo/android-swipelistview-sharp

Answer (score 0):

There is an equivalent for Xamarin.Android, called SwipeMenuListView-Sharp

https://github.com/WahidNasri/SwipeMenuListView-Sharp

This enables you to add buttons on each row (visible when swipe right or left as configured) and add actions to them.

It enables to to add swipe buttons depending on the ViewType of the ListView.
So I think it is what you want.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @LW001 I added some description